# How can i pass this component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, components

i want to show "favorite" items in my favorites component. but since i can't pass postList component to favorites component i don't know how to do it.

basically i want to show this favorite items in another page/component instead of home.js. [image]

Home.js

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { getDocs, collection, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { db, auth } from "../../firebase";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Sidebar from "../Sidebar/Sidebar";
    import "./Home.css";
    import PostList from "./PostList";

    const Home = ({ isAuth, setIsAuth }) => {
      const [postLists, setPostList] = useState([]);
      const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
      const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(localStorage.getItem("dam"));

      useEffect(() => {
        const getPosts = async () => {
          const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
          setPostList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        };

        getPosts();
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        const localData = localStorage.getItem("dam") ?? [];
        setFavorites(localData);
      }, [setFavorites]);

      const addFavorite = (favorite) => {
        setFavorites((prevfavorites) => [...prevfavorites, favorite]);

        localStorage.setItem("dam", JSON.stringify(favorites));
      };

      return (
        <div className="containers">
          <div className="sidebar">
            <Sidebar isAuth={isAuth} setIsAuth={setIsAuth} />
            <div className="centered">
              <div className="bordered">
                <button id="ado">
                  <Link to="/createpost">+ Add API</Link>
                </button>
              </div>

              <div className="new-container">
                {postLists?.map((post) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <PostList
                        post={post}
                        addFavorite={addFavorite}
                        key={post.id}
                      />
                    </>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="another">
              <h2>FAVORITE ITEMS</h2>
              {postLists
                .filter((post) => favorites.includes(post.id))
                .map((post) => (
                  <PostList post={post} addFavorite={addFavorite} key={post.id} />
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Home;
```

PostList.js

```
    import React from "react";

    const PostList = ({ post, addFavorite }) => {
      const { linkin, title, imageURL, photoURL, name, id } = post;

      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <div className="post">
              <div className="postimage">
                <div className="del"></div>

                <div className="images">
                  <a href={linkin}>
                    <p className="ss">{title}</p>

                    <img src={imageURL} id="img-photo" />
                  </a>
                  <div className="uploader">
                    <img src={photoURL} />

                    <p>by {name}</p>
                  </div>
                  {addFavorite && (
                    <div className="butons">
                      <button onClick={() => addFavorite(id)} id="favori">
                        +
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default PostList;
```

and a empty Favorites.js component.

Favorites.js

```
favorites here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a react custom hook, or useContext hook.
With this two option, you can share and access the favorite items in your favorites component. These hooks help share state globally.